# Java code refactoring issue

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a similary class structure as below:

```
       public class Foo extends Base{
                ...
        }   

        public class Bar extends Base{
                ...
        }

        public class Aos extends Base{
                ...
        }

        public class Wrap{
            List<Foo> getFooList();
            List<Bar> getBarList();
            List<Aos> getAosList();
        }

Fold fooFold = getFooFold();
Fold barFold = getBarFold();
Fold aosFold = getAosFold();

    // Code to refactor
        for (Obj e : fooFold.getObj()) {
               Foo foo = new Foo(.., .., ..);
               for (Som s: e.getSom())) {
                    doSom();
               }
               wrap.getFooList().add(foo);
        }

        for (Obj e : barFold.getObj()) {
               Bar bar = new Bar(.., .., ..);
               for (Som c : e.getSom())) {
                    doSom();
               }
            wrap.getBarList().add(bar);
        }

        for (Obj e : aosFold.getObj()) {
             Aos aos = new Aos(.., .., ..);
             for (Som c : e.getSom())) {
                    doSom();
            }
               wrap.getAosList().add(aos);
        }
```

How can i refactor the for-loops? (The for-loops are a "little" more complex. The 
logic do always the same. The iteration over the list, the creation of the object and adding the object to the list are different. )

Comment: are `getFooSpecObj()`, `getAosSpecObj()`, and `getBarSpecObj()` have to be called seperately? In that case, you have to have 3 for- loops. Apart from that extract the nested for into a private function

Comment: Yes they have to called seperatly

Comment: What exactly do you want to refactor then?

Comment: Could you post some code that compiles?

Comment: The calls to doSom() in the loops - as far as I can see, they don't use the current iteration of Som, so what are they for? If it was c.doSom() or doSom(c) it would make more sense. Also, I hope those aren't your real variable names. Variable names should be descriptive.

Comment: @NickJ thats not the real variable names. The project iam working on use this construct with the for-loops for each object extending the "Base" object. Sorry, it should doSom(c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the functions are separate, the only thing you can refactor is put the common code in a private function

```
private doCommonThings(Base e) {
      for (Som c : e.getSom())) {
            doSom();
       }
}
```

then use it in all your loops

```
for (Obj e : getFooSpecObj()) {
       Foo foo = new Foo(.., .., ..);
       doCommonThings(e);
       wrap.getFooList().add(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is really as simple as you have it above, you will probably find that any refactoring that you do to simplify it, will only end up making it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is hard to judge about re-factoring direction as some parts of implementation are missing. Here is  my guess how to proceed in this case:

```
public class ListBase< T >  {

    private List< T > _list;

    public ListBase(ListFactory< List < T > > list_factory ){
       _list = ( List< T > ) list_factory.create ( );
    }

    public void foreach ( CallbackInterface< T > callback ){
       for ( T i :getList( ) ){
           callback.process ( i );
       }
    }

    public List < T > getList ( ){
       return _list;
    }
}

public interface ListFactory< T >  {
    List< T > create ();
}

public interface CallbackInterface < I > {
    void process ( I element );
}

class ListFactorryArrayList < T > implements ListFactory < T > {
    @Override
    public ArrayList< T > create( ) {
        return new ArrayList < T > ( );
    }
}
public class Wrap {

    public ListBase< Foo > _listFoo = new ListBase<Foo >( new ListFactorryArrayList < List<Foo> > () );
    public ListBase< Bar > _listBar = new ListBase<Bar >( new ListFactorryArrayList < List<Bar> > () );
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wrap w = new Wrap ();
        w._listFoo.getList().add( new Foo () );
        w._listFoo.foreach( new CallbackInterface <Foo > () {

            @Override
            public void process(Foo element) {
                // do smth with foo object
            }
        });
    }
}
```